# How to use back-reference of sed replacement command correctly considering a special Regular Expression

Tags: regex, linux, sed, regular-language, backreference

I am learning the sed s/regexp/replacement/ command on linux.

There are some numbers from phone.txt

```
(555)555-1212
(555)555-1213
(555)555-1214
(666)555-1215
(777)555-1217
```

I'd like to use the regular expression (which I have tested on https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html)

```
 (\(555\))(.*-)(.*$)
```

to match numbers which begin with (555). And then I want the output of these three parts of these matched number as: (an example for number (555)555-1212)

```
Area code: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1212
```

I tried the following command:

```
cat phone.txt | sed 's/\(\\\(555\\\)\)\(.*-\)\(.*$)/Area code: \1 Second: \2 Third: \3/'
```

But the system gave me:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 66: Unmatched ( or \(
```

The general command for all numbers was:

```
cat phone.txt | sed 's/\(.*)\)\(.*-\)\(.*$\)/Area code: \1 Second: \2 Third: \3/'
```

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm

But I just want to execute sed on numbers which **begins with (555)** and add it to the output through **back reference**.

Could you tell me how to write this special command correctly?

Comment: You may use `sed -E 's/(\(555\))(.*-)(.*)/Area code: \1 Second: \2 Third: \3/'`. With POSIX ERE syntax, you may escape parentheses as in all common online regex testers.

Comment: When you use BRE, you don't have to double-escape `(` to get a literal parenthesis; just use the parenthesis on its own, so `(` instead of `\\\\(`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ypu are using POSIX BRE syntax in your `sed` command, and in such patterns, unescaped parentheses match literal parentheses. Escaped parentheses there define capturing groups.

You may use

```
sed -E 's/(\(555\))(.*-)(.*)/Area code: \1 Second: \2 Third: \3/'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/SvZ2Pn)

Literal parentheses in POSIX ERE syntax (enabled with `-E` option) are escaped as in all common online regex testers, and unescaped parentheses define capturing groups.

Comment: Thank you, that is the point I want to know. It is important to feed sed with -E or -r or --regexp-extended to enable extended regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You can generalize using the formatting included in the string to pick out the first `555`, the second `555` and the third `1212` without limiting yourself to any specific prefix within the `s/find/replace/` substitution form of `sed`. You can then limit as needed by including a matching condition before the substitution where you would enter your `555` or `666`, etc...

To include the pattern match along with the substitution, you use the following form:

```
sed '/pattern/s/find/replace/'
```

To make the pattern match suppress output for all lines except those that match the pattern you pass the `-n` option to suppress printing of pattern space, and include a `p` at the end of the substitute form to explicitly print those lines that match, e.g.

```
sed -n '/pattern/s/find/replace/p'
```

Now, let's turn to your problem at hand. To limit your reformatted output to only those lines beginning with `(555)` you would do:

```
$ sed -n '/^(555)/s/^(\([^)]*\))\([^-]*\)-\(.*\)$/Area code: (\1) Second: \2- Third: \3/p' file
Area code: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1212
Area code: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1213
Area code: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1214
```

(**note:** the backreferences capture only the numbers and not the `(..)` or `'-'`)

To reformat all lines, you would remove the `-n` and `/pattern/` along with the final `p`, using only the base `sed 's/find/replace/` form,  e.g.

```
$ sed 's/^(\([^)]*\))\([^-]*\)-\(.*\)$/Area code: (\1) Second: \2- Third: \3/' file
Area code: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1212
Area code: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1213
Area code: (555) Second: 555- Third: 1214
Area code: (666) Second: 555- Third: 1215
Area code: (777) Second: 555- Third: 1217
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. So the regular expression `^(\([^)]*\))\([^-]*\)-\(.*\)$` is POSIX BRE syntax, the escaped parentheses define capturing groups (thanks to @wiktor-stribiżew 's answer). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct. I prefer BRE if there is a reasonable way to form the REGEX.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to accept your answer but the answer from @wiktor-stribiżew told me the point I want to know. Your answer worked well too.

Comment: No problem, it's completely up to you. Glad to help.